# How to fix procedure with many parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure

I have a procedure with four parameters and one of my combinations is wrong I don't get a result when i try to exec p_shearch_vehicle @idCustomer=1,@ResultCount=2.

My procedure looks like this:

```
create procedure    p_shearch_vehicle3
@IdCustomer int,
 @idGroupVehicle int = null,
 @ResultCount int= null,
 @Radiant int= null 
 as
 begin
 if @IdCustomer is null
    begin
        print 'The argument cannot be null'
        return 
    end
 declare @start geography
 SET @start = (select location from Customer where idCustomer=@idCustomer )
 ---@Result null group null radiant null
    if @ResultCount is null and @idGroupVehicle is null and @Radiant is null
        begin
    select top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
        end
             ---@Result null  radiant null
            else if @ResultCount is null and @Radiant is null
            begin
    select  top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle and (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
             ---@Result null  
            else if @Radiant is null
            begin
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
             ---@@idGroupVehicle  null @Radiant is null
            else if  @idGroupVehicle is null and @Radiant is null
            begin
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
            ---@idGroupVehicle is null and @ResultCount is null
            else if  @idGroupVehicle is null and @ResultCount is null
            begin
    select top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000   <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
        --- @idGroupVehicle is null 
            else if  @idGroupVehicle is null 
            begin
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000   <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
            --- all options
    else
    begin
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
 end
GO
```

My error is with `@idGroupVehicle = NULL AND @Radiant = NULL`; with this combination, I don't get any result, but when I check like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_search_vehicle]
    @IdCustomer int,
    @ResultCount int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF @IdCustomer IS NULL
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The argument cannot be null'
        RETURN 
    END

    DECLARE @start geography
    SET @start = (select location from Customer where idCustomer=@idCustomer )
select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            end
            go
```

My result is:

[image]

Can someone explain why I can get this result in my procedure?

Comment: Four parameters is "many"?

Comment: Could you try to put BEGIN...END for each IF statement to clearly see the scope of the IF statements?

Comment: @Blindy for you is many bot

Answer (score 0):

I think you're expecting this condition to be hit first:

```
else if  @idGroupVehicle is null and @Radiant is null
```

But actually, this condition is getting hit first:

```
else if @Radiant is null
```

So in that case, when @Radiant is NULL, the SELECT statement firing is this one:

```
select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
```

I bet if you ran THAT select statement by itself, it also wouldn't return data.

In your decision structure, the 'else if @Radiant is NULL' check is BEFORE the 'else if @idGroupVehicle is NULL and @Radiant is NULL' check.

This means the SELECT statement within that 'else if @Radiant is NULL' check will get ran, then no other SELECT statements will get ran after it.

If you want more than one SELECT statement to fire, you should change your 'ELSE IF' statements to just 'IF' statements.

Or, you could rearrange your code to have the 'else if @idGroupVehicle is NULL and @Radiant is NULL' check come before the 'else if @Radiant is NULL' check.

Hope this help!

Comment: Based on the URL of your link containing your user name/profile site, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must* disclose that it's your site in your post. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).